# PHP and MySQL to integer

Tags: php, mysql, int

I got some problems with PHP and MySQL. Im trying to get a integer variable from MySQL count. Here is my code :

```
    $question="SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM Friends";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$question);

    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($link,$result);
    $how_many=$row['num'];
    $how_many=(int)$how_many;

    $how_many=$how_many+1;
    echo $how_many;
```

And as a result i always get a 1 or it can't be showed. Please guys help i will be very gratefull.

Comment: you're using `mysqli` in your query but in your fetch you are using `mysql` instead

Comment: I tried to use mysqli but it still can't show me a number.

Comment: You can't mix both API's, read the related question to know further

Comment: I just fixed it and the problem is still with me. i will edit my question in moment